# How to get the row and column of US PLSS sections?

Tags: land-survey, order, plss, column, township-range-section

How to get the row and column of US Public Land Survey System (PLSS) township sections? Sure, looking at a diagram I can quickly fill in a lookup table by hand,

```
section,column,row
1,6,6
2,5,6...
36,6,1
```

but isn't there some programmatic way to deal with Boustrophedon order?

Answer (score 0):

OK I have finally hammered out the algorithm! I include both US and Canadian solutions. I use "Bureau of Land Management Geographic Coordinate Database (GCDB) Publication Point IDs" format, e.g., the `6,1` above is written `600100`, referring to the southwest corner of section 36.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings q(all);
for ( 1 .. 36 ) {
    my ( $x, $y );
    printf "SWcrSec%02d", $_;
    $y = 6 - int( ( $_ - 1 ) / 6 );
    $x = abs( ( $_ - 1 ) % 12 - 6 ) + $y % 2;
    p( "US", $x, $y );    #US Public Land Survey System
    $y = int( ( $_ - 1 ) / 6 ) + 1;
    $x = abs( ( $_ - 1 ) % 12 - 6 ) + ( $y - 1 ) % 2;
    p( "CA", $x, $y );    #Canadian Dominion Land Survey
    print "\n";
}
sub p { printf " %s:%d00%d00", @_; }

SWcrSec01 US:600600 CA:600100
SWcrSec02 US:500600 CA:500100
SWcrSec03 US:400600 CA:400100
SWcrSec04 US:300600 CA:300100
SWcrSec05 US:200600 CA:200100
SWcrSec06 US:100600 CA:100100
SWcrSec07 US:100500 CA:100200
SWcrSec08 US:200500 CA:200200
...
SWcrSec36 US:600100 CA:600600
```

And here's the reverse,

```
sub cr2bUS {
    my ( $x, $y ) = @_;
    if   ( $y % 2 ) { return 6 * ( 6 - $y ) + $x; }
    else            { return 6 * ( 6 - $y ) + 7 - $x; }
}

sub cr2bCA {
    my ( $x, $y ) = @_;
    if   ( $y % 2 ) { return 6 * ( $y - 1 ) + 7 - $x; }
    else            { return 6 * ( $y - 1 ) + $x; }
}
```

Indeed, perhaps someone might wish to expand this answer for the general case of a P x Q sized boustrophedon, coordinate origin at corner A,B, starting "ox plowing" at corner E,F and proceeding in direction T, with initial number Q...

[Example implementation](https://www.jidanni.org/geo/house_numbering/grids/utilities/Bou2colrow.pm)